# Too many defective pixels?

Tags: hot-pixels, stuck-pixel

I just bought a cheap action-camera and start experimenting with RAW format. The output file has some defective pixels. I know that they can be "removed", but it seems to me that they are too many. I would like to know if this is normal or not. See [here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOnsapccqpSAEzOY5yut6G2XU4TClcafXBSMQPfK2zhuMPwit9q-JZRCl7tdFgfXA?key=anpFLUYtaEFSQkxDT3VxcWtycEtPQ2tUMUpPSVlB) a test image (10 seconds exposure). And a [second](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNltL01OPAex4Yj_BiQPzPJyvOPVPyu9oKHCTsF7YSeKskjUVjJ8uIC4uDy4gqPtw?key=RDllR0ZWYllSVDBySjZnQVI3WGJVMzV5U3g1MWJR) one (automatic exposure, cap on).

The sensor is Sony IMX078.

Thank you.

Comment: When working with long exposures, hot pixels are common

Comment: @Janas You mean the number is increasing with exposure?

Comment: What camera are you using? If it's a low-quality camera, then perhaps lots of hot pixels is common.

Comment: @scottbb Hawkeye Firefly 7s, Sony sensor (they claim).

Comment: Those look like hot pixels, not stuck pixels.  They're normal for longer exposures on *all* sensors.  There's a process called [dark frame removal](http://www.pearsonfaces.com/fpsurgeon/2007/04/better-dark-frame-subtraction-in.html) that is often used automatically in cameras to remove them on long exposures.

Comment: @StephenG I do not know which name is correct. I will edit the post. I am concerned about the number of defective pixels.

Comment: It's not a defect.  It's quite normal - the best DSLRs have these issues in long exposures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any image sensor you will get some hot pixels and these will be noticeable in long exposures - but easily fixed in post processing. Unfortunately what is a 'normal' amount is very subjective, most sensor manufacturers do mention a percentage of pixels that may or may not work as no manufacturing process is 100% perfect, the more well known manufacturers Sony, Canon etc will have higher quality control than less known or knock off brands.

1) You may have an older / cheaper Sony sensor in your camera that may have a few dodgy pixels
2) You could have a dodgy camera

If you are concerned and the camera is within warranty have a chat with the manufacturer and you may get it replaced or repaired.

Comment: Do you have an opinion on the posted image? Normal, too many?

Comment: Well personally, if I didnt pay too much for the camera I would keep an eye on the issue and if it didnt get any worse then I'd live with it. However if I'd paid a reasonable amount I'd personally contact the manufacturer. The old 'you get what you paid for' may apply here :)

Comment: I didn't have high expectations from camera; I was surprised to see so many defective pixels from a Sony sensor.  Thank you.

Comment: To get a feeling of how many in total there might be, you could find something pure black like a sheet and do a long exposure, this way there will be no distractions in the image and you can better make the call on whether to return the camera or not